# Message box in Windows is shown in Korean or Chinese language

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2013

I am new to programming and tried to make a simple message box with title "Title" and message "hello". Instead of the desired result after building and debugging the project, it shows the title and message in Korean or Chinese language.

Here are my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
int _stdcall WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,  LPSTR lpszCmdline, int nCmdShow)
{
    MessageBox(0,"Hello","Treat",0);
    return (0);
}'
```

Comment: You should check locale for non-unicode programs as described here: https://www.coscom.co.jp/learnjapanese801/japanesefont/nonunicode_win7.html

Comment: That's not what your program looks like, you used (char*) casts to get the compiler to stop telling you that you are doing it wrong.  You have to use wide strings, L"Hello" and L"Treat".

Answer (score 1):

Try  `MessageBox(0,_T("Hello"),_T("Treat"),0);`

_T is a macro defined within <windows.h> which will convert your string constants to UTF-16 if building for the Unicode version of Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `MessageBoxA`, which takes ASCII strings, instead of `MessageBox`.